# Will the friends of friends that I put in the 'Restricted' list, see items in my profile that I set to be viewable by my 'Friends of Friends'?

Tags: facebook, privacy

An attempt at illustrating this (where '**->**' means 'is/am friends with'):

> I **->** a friend in my 'Restricted' list (hereby known as '*R1*') **->**
>   R1's friend (hereby known as '*R2*')

Will R2 (assuming that R2 is not a Facebook friend of mine) be able to to view items in my profile that I set to be viewable by my 'Friends of Friends'? What I would like to know is if R2 will be restricted from viewing items in my profile due to his/her connection with R1 (who is in the 'Restricted' list), or will he/she be able to view items in my profile since he/she is a friend of my friend (R1), as per my profile's privacy settings.

**Will the friends of friends that I put in the 'Restricted' list, see the items in my profile that I set to be viewable by *my* 'Friends of Friends'?**

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this, and the answer is yes. Despite account A putting all its mutual friends with account B on "restricted", account B (unfriended for the sake of the experiment) was able to see friends-of-friends content.